# VERBOSE-3:FlutterPlatformViews.mm(239) Check failed: factories_.count(idString) == 0. Can anyone help me with this problem

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-ios

```
// Copyright 2013 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#import "FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin.h"

#import "FLTCookieManager.h"

#import "FlutterWebView.h"

@implementation FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin

+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar>*)registrar {
  FLTWebViewFactory* webviewFactory =
      [[FLTWebViewFactory alloc] initWithMessenger:registrar.messenger];  


[registrar registerViewFactory:webviewFactory 
withId:@"plugins.flutter.io/webview"];

  [FLTCookieManager registerWithRegistrar:registrar];  

}

@end
```

[This is the first error location when run in xcode.][1]

```
2022-11-07 16:32:18.912377+0800 Runner[51398:324228] Metal API Validation Enabled. 


2022-11-07 16:32:19.150893+0800 Runner[51398:324228] [VERBOSE-3:FlutterPlatformViews.mm(239)] Check failed: factories_.count(idString) == 0.


CoreSimulator 857.7 - Device: iPhone 14 Pro (A307DF5E-C1CA-4F0D-8188-9C52CCA79B51) - Runtime: iOS 16.0 (20A360) - DeviceType: iPhone 14 Pro. 
(lldb).
```

[I have already done flutter clean, flutter pub get and pod install, but the error is the same.][2]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/29qTL.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4cUl.png
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider posting your code as text instead of an image. See this post to read on how your can do it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/407041

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.